# What is the best way to use the mysql charm in Juju with dynamic database credientials?

Tags: bash, juju

I am creating a Juju charm to encompass many Django development projects. I have the charm installing Django, wsgi, and Apache2. Django uses a separate database, user, and password for every project created. How do I provide these credentials to the charm when the mysql charm has only one set of database credentials? I would like to parse the python paths for all installed Django projects and have a mysql charm ready to use with them.
As you can see below, the user will have to set these manually and change them when a new/different Django project is deployed to the cloud.

```
user=`relation-get user`
password=`relation-get password`
host=`relation-get host`
database=`relation-get database`
```

My question: Do I need to create a bash script to auto-create mysql charms with a correlating name to the Django project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a new mysql charm with a new interface that can allocate dbs dynamically when requested and use that from your django charm, or deploy the projects as individual services.

Effectively the new interface for mysql would have the hooks allocate new dbs as requested by the connecting service, instead of creating them when the new service is related/connected to mysql.

Another alternative, fix your django projects to use table prefixes, which I thought they already did (or maybe that's app table prefixing with project).

***Edit***

The *best* solution might be to just use an admin interface relation, which gives you the root user on mysql and then you can create additional dbs as needed (pointed out to me on irc by clint) for all the django projects installed.

Comment: Ya, makes sense. Only, there does not seem to be much documentation  on interfaces in the web. Have I overlooked it somewhere?

Comment: -1, there is no need to fork the mysql charm. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

The mysql charm has multiple interfaces, one of which is designed specifically for your app to have admin privileges over the whole server. So you would just make your relation

```
requires:
  db:
    interface: mysql-root
```

This will guarantee you a "root" users with privileges that you can use to create databases/users/etc. You won't get a 'database', since you can create any database, so keep that in mind.